# Recommended size of a thread pool where several related tasks are submitted once

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to make a program that will execute a variable number of possibly (but not certainly) computationally heavy tasks in parallel. These tasks (of Runnable type) will all be submitted at the same time and the thread pool should shut down once all these tasks are complete (in other words, the pool will only need to accept the initial tasks and nothing more).

In most of the answers that I found on this site, the question was about a server-based task (I am running my program on a decent desktop) or a pool that accepts tasks over irregular time intervals. In the questions that were not specific about the use, the answer was usually "it depends."

I have basically zero experience with threads, so I really do not know what is the optimal "thread count to task intensity" ratio.

For context, the program that I am working on deals with collections of matrices (represented by 3D arrays) where each matrix can contain up to 1000x1000 elements. One of the tasks may be to perform a convolution operation, and each task is an operation on one of the matrices in the collection.

Is there a recommendation for this specific type of problem?

Comment: Well, a "software" thread in java is ~1MB. So, it really depends on how much memory you have to spare. Having the memory to back a large number of threads, doesn't necessarily mean that your CPU can handle the *too* frequent context-switches, resulting in low performance

Comment: Given that your tasks seem to be CPU-bound and not IO-bound, if the goal is to be as fast as possible, using the number of CPU cores is probably the optimal way: you use all the cores, and run at most 1 task on each core, thus reducing context switches. But of course that also means that the last submitted tasks won't run until all the previous ones have completed.

Comment: The final output of the whole operation will need every thread to complete, so the only thing I am concerned about is getting from task submission to thread pool close as quickly as possible. Does this affect how many threads I should run @JBNizet, or should I just stick to the number of cores?

Comment: The number of cores is probably your best bet in that case.

Comment: This appears to be the general consensus, along with some experimentation. I'll give it a try. @JBNizet

Comment: @GhostCat Yes you are right. I was too quick to answer and didn't read his question carefully. He wanted to know how many threads can be run in parallel, without bottle-necking his system and not how many threads how could run at the same time. My answer is wrong, but not close to nonsense. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same that you hear when that question gets asked for a server: don't make *assumptions*, make **experiments**.

Try to identify (worst case: guess) the typical hardware setup that your users are running your software on. Then make sure you can do nicely automated performance testing. And then see what happens.

But thing is: that won't help much. You see, when you run your own server, you are (hopefully) in control about the workload that these machines are busy with. For a desktop setup, where remote users run your code on their boxes ... you have **zero** insights what else is running there. You might find that 16 threads are fine for 50% of the users. But the rest is maybe doing *a lot* of other things on their machines, and 16 is already way too much for them.

And that is the real crux. No matter what number you find "good to go" for a specific hardware configuration, you have no control about *other* workloads.

From that point of view, I would be pretty conservative. For a CPU intensive workload "too many" threads isn't helpful anyway, so go with the number of CPUs, or better number of cores as starting point.

Beyond that, what might be really helpful here: add some sort of "data gathering" to your application. Meaning: have it call home regularly, to tell you things like: "this is the hardware I am running on, I am using X threads, and the *other* workload on the system is Y". That might help you to get to some heuristics to *adapt* to the most important user setups. But be diligent about *what* data to collect. Define the questions you want to be answered upfront, and then pull the data you need to answer these questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you workload is computationally intensive (CPU bound) you might want to look into [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) which implements [worker stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing).

> A ForkJoinPool differs from other kinds of ExecutorService mainly by virtue of employing work-stealing: all threads in the pool attempt to find and execute tasks submitted to the pool and/or created by other active tasks (eventually blocking waiting for work if none exist). This enables efficient processing when most tasks spawn other subtasks (as do most ForkJoinTasks), as well as when many small tasks are submitted to the pool from external clients.